# Sample data in azure mobile services

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm totally new to Azure technologies. I developed a Mobile Service Azure from Visual Studio 2013 Up. 4, I added my **DataObjects**, **Controllers** etc. The site is well published on Azure and when I'm test it, the Help pages returns me sample data, like this:

```
    [
  {
    "fkfrom": 1,
    "fkto": 2,
    "amount": 3.1,
    "summaryID": 4,
    "borrowerFullName": "sample string 5",
    "lenderFullName": "sample string 6"
  },
  {
    "fkfrom": 1,
    "fkto": 2,
    "amount": 3.1,
    "summaryID": 4,
    "borrowerFullName": "sample string 5",
    "lenderFullName": "sample string 6"
  },
  {
    "fkfrom": 1,
    "fkto": 2,
    "amount": 3.1,
    "summaryID": 4,
    "borrowerFullName": "sample string 5",
    "lenderFullName": "sample string 6"
  }
]
```

Now, when I test it with headers and body, I get a `500/Internal server error`, and the body answer is `{"message":"An error has occurred."}`

I highly appreciate suggestions and any kind of help.

Comment: Have you checked the logs for your mobile service on the portal? It should list the error details. post those here for more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you haven't changed the default database initializer. the DropCreateDatabase initializer won't work in Azure. You have to use something else like ClearDatabaseSchemaifModelChanges.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/